# S3 bucket access restricted to VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vpn, policy, bucket

I've created some sort of private documentation for my infra team, uploaded to S3 Bucket and would like to make it private, accessible only on our VPN.

I tried to allow those vpn ip ranges: 173.12.0.0/16 and 173.11.0.0/16 but i keep getting 403 - forbidden (inside vpn).

Can someone help me debug or find where im messing up?

My bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "vpnOnly",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::calian.io/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "173.12.0.0/16",
                        "173.11.0.0/16"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, S3 requests go **via the Internet**, so the requests would 'appear' to be coming from a public IP address.

Alternatively, you could add a **VPC Endpoint for S3**, which would make the request come 'from' the **private IP addresses**.

You might also consider using [Amazon S3 Access Points](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/access-points/) to control the access to the bucket.

Comment: You are right, that's what's happening. I was thinking to use cloudfront + cognito + lambda edge to get some kind of Auth before accessing my S3 bucket. That should work, right?

Comment: This is simply to restrict access to your network via VPN? That sounds like overkill. Feel free to create a new question with more details of what you are wanting to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Since VPC endpoints are only accessible from Amazon EC2 instances inside a VPC, a local instance must proxy all remote requests before they can
utilize a VPC endpoint connection. The following sections outline a DNS-based proxy solution that directs appropriate traffic from a corporate network to
a VPC endpoint for Amazon S3 as depicted in the following diagram.
[image: DNS-based proxy solution]

Answer (score 0):

From one of the machines you are attempting to access the S3 bucket from go to the "AWS Check My IP" endpoint at https://checkip.amazonaws.com/

From there confirm that the IP address you're seeing is inside of the range you have defined in your policy. My guess is it'll be different- instead you'll see the public ip address of your VPN or NAT Gateway/Instance, as your traffic is likely going over the internet to get to S3.

Once you've identified the IP address you're using you can either update the security group to include it, or look into solutions such as a VPC Endpoint to keep traffic on your private network.